# Changing EditText focus border

Tags: android, android-theme

I wanna ask how i can change EditText border then it on focus. I want to change original orange gradiant to my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi you can create gradient like this in the drawable folder.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
   <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#5a5a5a88"
                android:endColor="#14141488"
                android:angle="270" android:centerX="0.25"/>

   </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="80dp">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#5aff5a88"
                android:endColor="#14ff1488"
                android:angle="270" android:centerX="0.25"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: O! thx, but I have one more problem, I don't know why but i cant set the padding. :/

Answer (score 3):

create a file in the drawable folder. paste the code below.  also give appropriate images as you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"     
 android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"       
 android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_selected" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_selected" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
</selector>
```

This will work perfectly.

Comment: Thx its work, but I don't want use pictures, how I can set this in code with gradients?

Comment: you can create gradient like this